# Set cookie on click for specific element only

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Im trying to add a class when I click an element and keep it after page load via a cookie by using jQuery/javascript.

This is what I got so far, which gives it the class to the specific clicked element but of course doesn't keep it after page load:

```
jQuery("a.action.towishlist").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass("wishlisttest");
    localStorage.setItem('btnClicked', true);
 });



jQuery(document).ready(function (){
    var clicked = localStorage.getItem("btnClicked");
    if(clicked){
       jQuery(this).addClass("wishlisttest");
    }
});
```

There are multiple elements with the same name and class, so no ID. What I could use us the data.post attribute which has a unique ID.

```
<a href="#" class="action towishlist" data-post="{"action":"https:\/\/www.domain.com\/se\/wishlist\/index\/add\/","data":{"product":3766,"uenc":"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucG9zdGVyeS5jb20vanAvcG9zdGVycw,,"}}" data-action="add-to-wishlist" role="button"></a>
```

How do I set the cookie to identify the clicked element and keep the class?

Edit: After updating my platform I know have a new cleaner attribute to target `data-product-sku="1234"`

Comment: what are you really trying to accomplish ?

Comment: @RudyMartin Add a class to the clicked element, and to keep it after page load via a cookie.

Comment: if you can change the html, I would add an id to the html so you can target it - then you can save that id in your local storage instead of true

Comment: What you have tried is `localStorage`, this is different from a cookie (but it should suit your case well). Have you tried to log the value after `var clicked = localStorage.getItem("btnClicked");`? The value should be kept on reload, but actually `jQuery(this).addClass("wishlisttest");` should add the class to `document` instead of your button, that's where you need to change

Comment: @Pete Unfortunately I cant change the html, and I will have multiple elements with the same class. Only the data-post attribute differs.

Comment: @Kaddath Not sure what you mean or how to implement. Added a log but thats only gives me "true" and doesn't differ from what element I click on.

Comment: If you can't change the html your are in for trouble as it is invalid - you have not escaped the double quotes in your data-post attribute

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to save the part in `data-post` that is unique to the button, then to loop on the buttons to check for this value when you want to restore the state, something like this:

- you can use an array to store the values clicked, but you must use JSON to store it in localStorage
- considering the complexity of your `data-post` attribute, I think it's better to loop on all buttons and retreive it, and compare rather than using an attribute query selector because you will probably have problems with special chars escaping
- I corrected the `data-post` format using simple quotes `'` for the purpose of the test. If what you posted is the real attribute you may run into the problem that you cannot have double quotes like this in an attribute already delimited by double quotes

```js
jQuery("a.action.towishlist").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass("wishlisttest");
    
    //getting storage value, defaults to empty array if not set
    var clickedButtons = localStorage.getItem("btnClicked");
    if(!clickedButtons){
      clickedButtons = [];
    }else{
      clickedButtons = JSON.parse(clickedButtons);
    }
    
    //getting the product from data-post attribute which is JSON too
    var dataPost = jQuery(this).data('post');
    if(dataPost){
      dataPost = JSON.parse(dataPost);
      var productId = dataPost.data.product;
      
      //if not in array, push it
      if(clickedButtons.indexOf(productId) < 0){
        clickedButtons.push(productId);
      }
    }
    
    //re-format to JSON then store it
    clickedButtons = JSON.stringify(clickedButtons);
    localStorage.setItem('btnClicked', clickedButtons);
});



jQuery(document).ready(function (){
    //getting storage value, defaults to empty array if not set
    var clickedButtons = localStorage.getItem("btnClicked");
    if(!clickedButtons){
      clickedButtons = [];
    }else{
      clickedButtons = JSON.parse(clickedButtons);
    }
    
    //loop on all buttons, decode the attribute and test if in the saved array
    jQuery("a.action.towishlist").each(function(){
      //getting the product from data-post attribute which is JSON too
      var dataPost = jQuery(this).data('post');
      if(dataPost){
        dataPost = JSON.parse(dataPost);
        var productId = dataPost.data.product;

        //if in array, add class to the button
        if(clickedButtons.indexOf(productId) > -1){
          jQuery(this).addClass("wishlisttest");
        }
      }
    });
});

//TODO: add code to clear localStorage item when cart is cleared of some other condition
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="action towishlist" data-post='{"action":"https:\/\/www.domain.com\/se\/wishlist\/index\/add\/","data":{"product":3766,"uenc":"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucG9zdGVyeS5jb20vanAvcG9zdGVycw,,"}}' data-action="add-to-wishlist" role="button"></a>
<a href="#" class="action towishlist" data-post='{"action":"https:\/\/www.domain.com\/se\/wishlist\/index\/add\/","data":{"product":3767,"uenc":"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucG9zdGVyeS5jb20vanAvcG9zdGVycw,,"}}' data-action="add-to-wishlist" role="button"></a>
<a href="#" class="action towishlist" data-post='{"action":"https:\/\/www.domain.com\/se\/wishlist\/index\/add\/","data":{"product":3768,"uenc":"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucG9zdGVyeS5jb20vanAvcG9zdGVycw,,"}}' data-action="add-to-wishlist" role="button"></a>
```

**EDIT**: if you have an attribute with a unique value which is of a simpler type (numeric/alphanumeric id), you just can skip the JSON decoding part:

```js
jQuery("a.action.towishlist").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass("wishlisttest");
    
    //getting storage value, defaults to empty array if not set
    var clickedButtons = localStorage.getItem("btnClicked");
    if(!clickedButtons){
      clickedButtons = [];
    }else{
      clickedButtons = JSON.parse(clickedButtons);
    }
    
    //getting the product from data-post attribute which is JSON too
    var productSku = jQuery(this).data('product-sku');
    if(productSku && clickedButtons.indexOf(productSku) < 0){
      clickedButtons.push(productSku);
    }
    
    //re-format to JSON then store it
    clickedButtons = JSON.stringify(clickedButtons);
    localStorage.setItem('btnClicked', clickedButtons);
});



jQuery(document).ready(function (){
    //getting storage value, defaults to empty array if not set
    var clickedButtons = localStorage.getItem("btnClicked");
    if(!clickedButtons){
      clickedButtons = [];
    }else{
      clickedButtons = JSON.parse(clickedButtons);
    }
    
    //loop on all buttons, decode the attribute and test if in the saved array
    jQuery("a.action.towishlist").each(function(){
      //getting the product from data-post attribute which is JSON too
      var productSku = jQuery(this).data('product-sku');
      if(productSku && clickedButtons.indexOf(productSku) > -1){
        jQuery(this).addClass("wishlisttest");
      }
    });
});

//TODO: add code to clear localStorage item when cart is cleared of some other condition
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="action towishlist" data-product-sku="1" data-action="add-to-wishlist" role="button"></a>
<a href="#" class="action towishlist" data-product-sku="2"  data-action="add-to-wishlist" role="button"></a>
<a href="#" class="action towishlist" data-product-sku="3"  data-action="add-to-wishlist" role="button"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, doesnt seems to save the value after page load unfortunately, but interesting anyhow. Might be the double quotes then. Trying this on a Magento platform, and thats default that they have double quotes in that attribute for some reason.

Comment: I update my magento setup, and its seems it changed attributes for this element - I can now now use `data-product-sku="1204"`. Do I need to change anything else then `post` to `data-product` in your snippet?

Comment: @Jerry I edited my answer. Note that I have kept the test `if(productSku)`, in the original answer it was to avoid errors trying to JSON parse `undefined` in case the data attribute is not here. In the edit it is kept to avoid pushing falsey values to the array if the data attribute is not here.